# Improving queries by select related with many related models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Im writing an app with most of the data started across different tables. I've recently installed Django debug toolbar and noticed that i have some duplicates and similar queries. Thanks to this Im somewhat skeptical about my queries and how I make them. They work but are they efficient?

**models**

```py
class Location(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    placeId = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    point = models.PointField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=True)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    current_location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="location", null=True)
    search_range = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=10, blank=True, null=True)
    objects = CustomAccountManager()

class Profile(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dummy_section = models.TextField(max_length=155, null=True, blank=True)

class Blocked(models.Model):
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_thats_blocking")
    blocked_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blocked_user")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Interactions(models.Model):
    IntChoices = (
        ("yes", "yes"),
        ("no", "no"),
    ) 

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="current_user")
    interacted_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="interacted_user")
    interacted = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="yes", choices=(IntChoices), db_index=True)
```

So what I'm querying is.

Getting all the potential profiles within my search_range so in location model. Then I'm getting interactions with users from the interaction model. If I had interacted with someone before I remove them from my potential users and then I'm removing blocked users from the blocked model.

```py
range_number = 10

allowed_users = Profile.objects.select_related('user').filter(user__current_location__point__distance_lte=(current_loc, Distance(km=int(range_number))))
   
blocked = Blocked.objects.select_related('user').filter(user__id=current_id).values('blocked_user')
        
users_taken_inter = Interactions.objects.select_related('user').filter(user__id=current_id).values('interacted_user')
        
users_not_taken_action = allowed_users.exclude(user__in=users_taken_action).exclude(user__in=blocked).exclude(user__id=current_id)
```

I know this works but I don't know how well. Im using pagination so on average I'm having 35 queries in 35/40ms. But can i remove duplicates and/or improve performance?